# Adding URL params to form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to merge URL params in a `form_tag`, but I am finding that I can't dictate what the params are as they are overwritten. The purpose of passing params is to provide filtering and ordering variables, and as such, I want them visible in the URL and not hidden.

The closest I've come is to do this:

```
form_tag( :controller => 'assets',:action => 'index', :params => params.merge(:order => 'name'), :method => :get) do
```

The problem is that the `:get` method is simply passed as another param and not actually as a method, so it resolves to a `POST`.

I've also tried the following, which also doesn't work.

```
form_tag(params.merge(:order => 'name', :method => :get) do
```

The path is correct, but the URL params are strangely formatted, as you see that the param isn't prefixed with a `&`, but is nevertheless lost when the form is submitted.

```
action="/assets?commit=Filter&amp;order=name&amp;utf8=%E2%9C%93" method="get"
```

Here is another example of the overwriting of the params. The following code will generate the underlying element of the form code, but the params will be removed.

```
form_tag(url_for(:order => 'name'), :method => :get) do
```

Underlying code, which the params will not get passed on submission:

```
action="/asset_ratings?order=name"
```

Answer (score 0):

in my experience, using a "hidden" input tag inside the form is the usual way:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag

Comment: This should be a comment. Linking answers aren't great - try to paraphrase and *then* link.